# Asp.net Table width not going above 100%

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I tried looking for similar questions but couldn't find any. My aspx file looks something like this

```
<div align="center" style="height: 350px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; width: 100%;">
    <asp:Table ID="tblReport" Font-Size="11px" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow Height="30px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#3b3b3b" Style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left !important; padding-left: 3px; color: #FFF; border-right: 1px solid #ddeaf7;" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

Now whenever there are too many columns, the width gets fixed to 100% even though I don't have a max-width property. And the text in the cell ends up in multiple lines. I want it to horizontally overflow out of the div instead.

**Edit:** Looks like adding this ended up fixing it.

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple html snippet to demonstrate -

```css
div {
  width: 10%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>H</th>
      <th>I</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT -**

Your updated code would look like -

```
<div align="center" style="height: 350px; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
    <asp:Table ID="tblReport" Font-Size="11px" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow Height="30px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#3b3b3b" Style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left !important; padding-left: 3px; color: #FFF; border-right: 1px solid #ddeaf7;" HorizontalAlign="Center">
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    </asp:Table>
</div>
```

Comment: But I don't want the table to be limited to 100% width. I want it to go more than that but it's not.

Comment: @Kash I've updated my snippet now. Its similar to what you have instead of giving 100%, i set my div to 10% to save time. *Is this how you want your table to look when it crosses the width of the div?*

Comment: That's how I want it to look but it doesn't seem to be working for me. The table is automatically setting its max width to the width of the div :/

Comment: @Kash I've made changes to your code and updated my post. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I pasted the same thing but it still doesn't seem to be working. At this point, I might end up manually writing HTML code instead. Thanks for the effort though. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Looks like something might be overriding your styles. Inspect and see, maybe that will give you an idea on how to proceed. Let me know if I can help.

Comment: So I ended up finding a way. Looks like `td { white-space: nowrap; }` did the trick